# How to DRY up some form code

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, partial-views, dry

Having a hard time with this because of the numerous objects that get passed around... how would you write a partial or whatever to DRY this up?

**inventory/new.html.erb**

```
<% Categorylist.includes(:itemlists).where(itemlists: { inventory_list: true }).each do |n| %>
  <div class="col-xs-4">
    <div class="form-group" style="font-size:75%">
      <h5> <%= n.name %> </h5>
        <% n.itemlists.each do |i| %>
          <%= number_field_tag "inventory[#{i.id}]", :quantity, min: 0, value: @inventory_params ? @inventory_params[i] : 0, class: "shrink_num_field" %>
          <%= label_tag i.name, i.name %>
          </br>
        <% end %>
    </div>
  </div>  
<% end %>
```

**request/new.html.erb**

```
<% Categorylist.includes(:itemlists).where(itemlists: { request_list: true }).each do |n| %>
  <div class="col-xs-4">
    <div class="form-group" style="font-size:75%">
      <h5> <%= n.name %> </h5>
        <% n.itemlists.each do |i| %>
          <%= number_field_tag "borrow[][#{i.id}]", :quantity, min: 0, value: @borrowparams ? @borrowparams[i] : 0, class: "shrink_num_field" %>
          <%= label_tag i.name, i.name %>
          </br>
        <% end %>
    </div>
  </div>  
<% end %>
```

Specifically, I'm having a hard time getting the partial to differentiate between `inventory_list` vs. `request_list` in the first line.

Comment: I don't have an environment set up to test this but couldnt you set a variable that was equal to either `'inventory_list'` or `'request_list'` and use that variable in your `where` clause? Similarly, you could just have a variable with your whole `where` clause.

Comment: Yeah I tried something like `locals, { list: :inventory_list}` but that didn't work, I think I'm struggling to set a local variable equal to a constant.

Comment: Take a look at section 3.4.4 and 3.4.5 of http://guides.rubyonrails.org/layouts_and_rendering.html#using-partials

Comment: i did and couldn't figure it out